# How to make PolygonCollider2D component add with a isTrigger ON?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As you can see in this part of my code, I'm adding a PolygonCollider2D to gameObject, but I need it to add with isTrigger set to true, because otherwise item's picking up system doesn't work.

Is there some way to make it happen?

```
void Start()
{
    GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = item.itemImage;
    Destroy(GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>());
    gameObject.AddComponent<PolygonCollider2D>();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`GameObject.AddComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html) returns the reference of the newly added component.

So you can simply store it and access it's according property [`Collider2D.isTrigger`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D-isTrigger.html)

```
var collider = gameObject.AddComponent<PolygonCollider2D>();
collider.isTrigger = true;
```